# Печать докуметов из браузера

Tags: print, google-chrome, javascript

Добрый день. Столкнулась с задачей, и, если честно, даже не представляю, с чего начать. Может, кто-либо из вас сможет подсказать, с чего начать искать даже.

Суть вопроса в чем:
Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось диалоговое окно для печати (браузер хром).
Может, есть какие-то механизмы, которые помогут настроить интеграцию js с плагином браузера для печати?

Comment: @sashiav, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите в сторону Javascript: window.print();

Comment: спасибо)буду пробовать)